# Changing header format python pandas to excel

Tags: python, pandas, date, header

Is there any chance to change the header format of my pandas dataframe which is wrote to an excel file.
Maybe it is unusual, but my header is composed of Dates and times and I want the 'cell format' of the excel file be 'date format'.

I tried something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'1899-12-30 00:00:00': [1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5,5.4]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',index=True)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

date_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd.mm.yyyy  hh:mm:ss'})
worksheet.set_row(0, 20, date_fmt)

writer.save()
```

but set_row appears to not change header formats. I also converted the dates to an excel serial date value, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you will need to do to get this working.

The first is to avoid the Pandas default header since that will set a cell header which can't be overwritten with `set_row()`. The best thing to do is to skip the default header and write your own (see [Formatting of the Dataframe headers](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers) section of the XlsxWriter docs).

Secondly, dates in Excel are formatted numbers so you will need to convert the string header into a number, or better to a datetime object (see the [Working with Dates and Time](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) section of the docs).

Finally '1899-12-30' isn't a valid date in Excel.

Here is a working example with some of these fixes:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({'2020-09-18 12:30:00': [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.4]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Turn off the default header and skip one row to allow us to insert a user
# defined header.
data.to_excel(writer,
              sheet_name='Sheet1', index=True,
              startrow=1, header=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Add a header format.
date_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd.mm.yyyy  hh:mm:ss'})

# Convert the column headers to datetime objects and write them with the
# defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(data.columns.values):

    # Convert the date string to a datetime object.
    date_time = datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # Make the column wider for clarity.
    worksheet.set_column(col_num + 1, col_num + 1, 20)

    # Write the date.
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, date_time, date_fmt)

writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems to be the best solution, to get rid of the original header.